# InternalOAuthError: Failed to fetch user profile

Tags: passport.js, apollo-server, passport-google-oauth

I'm trying to implement google auth using passport.js to a GraphQL API. The flow seems to be working fine and I get a jwt token with the correct user info encoded. However, I still get the following error sometimes in my console. Any help would be appreciated!

```sh
InternalOAuthError: Failed to fetch user profile
    at /Users/Lawand/Developer/mono-api/node_modules/passport-google-oauth20/lib/strategy.js:99:19
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/Lawand/Developer/mono-api/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:162:5)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:447:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

My passport config file:

```js
passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy(
      {
        clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
        callbackURL: 'http://localhost:4001/auth/google/callback',
        passReqToCallback: true,
      },
      (req, _accessToken, _refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        try {
          User.find({
            where: { id: profile.id },
          }).then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
            if (res.length === 0) {
              const newUser = {
                id: profile.id,
                firstName: profile.name?.givenName,
                lastName: profile.name?.familyName,
                email:
                  profile.emails &&
                  profile.emails[0] &&
                  profile.emails[0].value,
              }
              User.create({
                input: [newUser],
              }).then(() => {
                req.user = profile
                done(null, profile)
              })
            }
          })
          req.user = profile
          done(null, req.user)
        } catch (error: any) {
          done(error)
        }
      }
    )
  )
```

The request is then being passed to the callback:

```js
const startApolloServer = async () => {
  const app = express()
  const httpServer = http.createServer(app)
  /*
   * Create an executable GraphQL schema object from GraphQL type definitions
   * including autogenerated queries and mutations.
   * Read more in the docs:
   * https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/current/
   */
  const neoSchema = new Neo4jGraphQL({
    typeDefs,
    driver,
    config: {
      jwt: {
        secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET as string,
      },
    },
  })

  // Same ApolloServer initialization as before, plus the drain plugin.
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    context: ({ req }) => ({ req }),
    schema: neoSchema.schema,
    plugins: [ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer })],
  })

  googlePassportConfig()

  app.use(passport.initialize())

  app.get(
    '/auth/google',
    passport.authenticate('google', {
      scope: ['profile', 'email'],
    })
  )
  app.get(
    '/auth/google/callback',
    passport.authenticate('google', {
      failureRedirect: 'http://localhost:4001/graphql',
      session: false,
      scope: ['profile', 'email'],
      passReqToCallback: true,
    }),
    (req: any, res) => {
      const token = jwt.sign(
        { id: req?.user?.id },
        process.env.JWT_SECRET as string,
        { expiresIn: '7d' }
      )
      res.json({ token })
    }
  )

  // More required logic for integrating with Express
  await server.start()
  /*
   * Optionally, apply Express middleware for authentication, etc
   * This also also allows us to specify a path for the GraphQL endpoint
   */
  server.applyMiddleware({
    app,
    path,
  })

  // Modified server startup
  httpServer.listen({ host, port, path }, () => {
    console.log(` GraphQL server ready at http://${host}:${port}${path}`)
  })
}

startApolloServer()
```

Comment: i have same question too~~~ both package 'passport-google-oauth20' and 'passport-google-oauth2' have same question

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and what finally fixed my issue was changing from bodyParser in my route index.js to app.use(express.json()) for the middleware. That completely fixed my error and it's been working fine since.